# Ignore conditions in WHERE clause if empty

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I want to show data filtered by `WHERE` clause. I have applied some variables in place of condition values, Now how to get the data if no condition is applied. I have tried but it. it is working, if the values are given but it is not working if the values are not given.

What should it do?

It has 3 filters. If the **date** is selected then it should show data by given date. Again if the **source** is selected then it should show data by the given date and the given source. like this, it should work.

```
$date_from = NULL;  //the value will be given if the user selects the date range
$date_to = NULL;

$src_id = NULL;  // this value will be given if the user wants data from specific source
$gndr_id = NULL; // if user want data by gender

$leadSql = "SELECT 
            lead.id as lead_id
          , lead.name as lead_name
          , lead.phone as lead_phone
          , lead.email as lead_email 
          , gender.name as lead_gender
          , treatment.name as treatment_name
          , lead.date as lead_date
          , source.name  as  source_name
          , status.name  as status_name
          , lead.remark as lead_remark
        FROM lead 
        join treatment on treatment.id = lead.treatment_id
        join gender on gender.id = lead.gender_id
        join source on source.id = lead.source_id
        join status on status.id = lead.status_id

        where (lead.date BETWEEN $date_from and $date_to) and 
        (lead.source_id = $src_id ) and (lead.gender_id = $gndr_id)

        ORDER BY lead_date DESC";
```

Please suggest me some way to do it.

Comment: you could use a ternary operator inside the query, that's one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my knowledge stretches you need to include the whole WHERE line in a condictional statement to say if values exist apply the WHERE clause if not ignore it.

```
 if($date_from != NULL && $date_to != NULL .....){
     $where_clause = "where (lead.date BETWEEN $date_from and $date_to) and 
            (lead.source_id = $src_id ) and (lead.gender_id = $gndr_id)";
 }  else{
     $where_clause ="";
 }

$leadSql = "SELECT 
                lead.id as lead_id
              , lead.name as lead_name
              , lead.phone as lead_phone
              , lead.email as lead_email 
              , gender.name as lead_gender
              , treatment.name as treatment_name
              , lead.date as lead_date
              , source.name  as  source_name
              , status.name  as status_name
              , lead.remark as lead_remark
            FROM lead 
            join treatment on treatment.id = lead.treatment_id
            join gender on gender.id = lead.gender_id
            join source on source.id = lead.source_id
            join status on status.id = lead.status_id

            ".$where_clause."

            ORDER BY lead_date DESC";
```

you can adjust the if/else according to your needs. This is the simplest solution.
You can write a conditional statement for each variable and concatenate them together at the end.

```
$where = [];
$where_clause = '';

if ($date_from && $date_to) {
    $where[] = "(lead.date BETWEEN $date_from and $date_to)";
}

if ($src_id) {
    $where[] = "(lead.source_id = $src_id )";
}

if ($gndr_id) {
    $where[] = "(lead.gender_id = $gndr_id)";
}

if (count($where)) {
    $where_clause = 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
}
```